# Modifying Info.plist's CFBundleVersion in Xcode 5 with Asset Library enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, xcode5

With Xcode 5's new Asset Library, adding images and organizing them has never been easier. However, it seems as if it has broken some scripts I use for creating builds.

I have a script within my Run Script Phase that sets the `CFBundleVersion` to be the current timestamp within the plist. In the script, I execute this statement:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $timestamp" $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH
```

However, when this gets executed, the following statement displays:

```
Set: Entry, ":CFBundleVersion", Does Not Exist
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/SpacePyro/Library/DerivedData/BundleTest-duikdqngfmrovnagrcsvdcuxxstz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BundleTest.app/Info.plist
```

It seems like this happens on clean builds. The plist doesn't seem to get generated until midway through the build, presumably due to the Asset Libraries.

I've also used this command, and while it doesn't throw the error, it still blows away my changes (assume `INFO_PLIST="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/Info"`):

```
defaults write $INFO_PLIST CFBundleVersion $timestamp
```

This used to not be the case when I started using the Asset Library to organize my app icons and splash images. Anyone know why this happens? And better yet, is there a workaround to add this value to the plist? I've already tried placing the script in a pre-action build phase, as well as the post-action build phase. I've also tried running the command after the build has completed, but when I try to codesign and package it up, it says that the signature is invalid due to plist modification.

If no reasonable solution exists, I guess I could always de-migrate from Asset Libraries until I can get my scripts to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured this one out, and it was a silly one. Turns out you can just move the script phase to the very end. I didn't even know these were movable, or that it mattered! But by dragging the Run Script phase to the bottom as such, the scripts were able to run and modify things as needed.

[image: Build Phases]

Comment: I moved my main app's `Run script` phase after `Copy Bundle Resources' but before 'Embed App Extensions` and  `Embed Watch Content`.

Answer (score 21):

I had similar issue once, and here is what finally helped me out:

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

(Use **INFOPLIST_FILE** directly, not **$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH**)

Hope this could be useful .

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, In my case, I had a wrong file path to the XXX-Info.plist file:

Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File

I changed it it's actual location and start working.

[image: Description to where to change the wrong settings]

Comment: Xcode ask me to select a info.plist. After i did it, the path is a full path, which means sh cannot find the info.plist when invoked. So, change it to a **relative path**.

Answer (score 2):

If your plist file is `Preprocessed-Info.plist`, then change the value of "Preprocess Info.plist File" (`INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS`) to "Yes" (`true`) like this:

[image: this]

Answer (score 1):

Search in Build settings for $(SRCROOT) and remove it.

**transform it from** 
$(SRCROOT)/TestProject/Info.plist
**to**
TestProject/Info.plist

[image]